# Turn off ng-bootstrap animations for all unit tests

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In the application we disable animations globally by just injecting `NgbConfig` into the root component.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(ngbConfig: NgbConfig) {
    ngbConfig.animation = false;
  }
}
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/guides/animations

But how can we do this in unit tests? I mean without going into each and every test and inject `NgbConfig` there.

I'm importing an `AppTestingModule` in each test setup in order to do some common imports define providers and so on, but I still see no way to inject `NgbConfig` there..

Answer (score 3):

Looking into ng bootstrap sources I think you can provide your own class instead of `NgbConfig`.

```
class MyConfig {
  animation = false;
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {provide: NgbConfig, useClass: MyConfig},
    ],

})
export class AppTestingModule {}
```